# ASP.NET Identity: Erro de Autenticação

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Mudei a PK das tabelas do Identity de string para Int, porém
ao realizar o login o Identity não autentica, ele loga
normalmente mas não têm acesso a nenhum dos controllers
que requer permissão, volta para a Home.
Não sei se tem haver com o problema mas retirei a 
annotation de autorização do ManageController e debuguei
a action Index e na seguinte linha o resultado é sempre 0:

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
```

O que será que pode ser?

*Caso precisar de mais informações atualizarei o post.

Comment: `GetUserId` não é um método de extensão? Edite sua pergunta e coloque o código do método. Provavelmente o problema está ali.

Comment: Olá jbueno, é do próprio Identity mesmo: public static T GetUserId<T>(this IIdentity identity) where T : IConvertible;
Eu devo extender ele?

Comment: Isso pode ajudar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705074/asp-net-identity-2-user-identity-getuseridint-always-returns-0

Comment: Valeu Goku, mas já tinha visto essa resposta. E parece que é para autenticação de Claims e também não sei em qual classe que deve colocar esse método.

Comment: Há algum motivo para mudar de string para int? os ganhos em performance serão absolutamente irrelevantes! O método tenta pegar um int (`Getuserid<int>()`) e o campo no banco é string... Teria que mudar também esse método (e talvez outros) para fazer essa mudança. Sinceramente? Voltaria a PK para string e seria feliz.

Comment: Valeu Loudenvier!, mas se todas as tabelas usam string num deixaria o desempenho menor? E também a outra questão é que eu queria mostrar o código de algumas entidades no formulário, para caso o usuário quiser pesquisar por código será muito mais fácil decorar um número do que um código como o Guid.
E outra também é que as URLs seriam mais amigáveis, Exemplo: meusite com/Produto/Detalhes/25
Em relação ao banco eu já mudei de string para int, mas o problema ainda insiste.